# Draw Chart in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How I can Draw Chart like this in windows phone ?
the (x) line  is a numbers I detrmined it ; for example (1 , 2, 3, 4, ..)
and the (y) line is a values that I retrive it in specific way.

http://sdrv.ms/Yuy6O0

Comment: I just need the way or the controls I should use to do like this

Comment: I would take a look at some of the existing chart Controls available, here are some I heard of: Using the Silverlight 3 Toolkit in Windows Phone 7: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightwinphone/thread/5d6f1ed1-2667-4f1d-b5d4-9d809c7aa810/ amCharts: https://github.com/ailon/amCharts-Quick-Charts Touch Enabled Graph Control WP7: http://touchgraphwp7.codeplex.com/ All those also has the source code available, which you could use for inspiration if you want to write your own Controls instead. I have only used the Silverlight Toolkit method myself and it worked fine in Windows P